# I cant find my follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cant find my follower Serena and for some reason most normal methods don't work sleeping waiting getting a dog and i have no other way I'm on Xbox and i need help please

Comment: Did you ask her to leave you service? Did she die? Did you get a new follower?